# Transforming adjacent links to a list using XLST

Tags: xslt

I'm looking for some help with XSLT Tranforms.

I'm currently transforming links that match the format:

```
<link type="button" url="/page.html" text="Do something" />
```

By using the transform:

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <a target="_blank" href="{@url}" title="{@text}">
        <xsl:if test="@type='button'">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">btn</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Which gives me the output:

```
<a class="btn" title="Do Something" href="/page.html" target="_blank">Do Something</a>
```

But now I'm looking to be able to detect when multiple links with the type "button" are grouped together like this:

```
<link type="button" url="/page.html" text="Do something" />
<link type="button" url="/page.html" text="Do something else" />
```

And output like so:

```
<ul class="btns">
    <li><a href="page.html" title="Do something" target="_blank" class="btn testing">Do something</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.html" title="Do something else" target="_blank" class="btn testing">Do something else</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone assist on this?

Thanks,
C.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use an XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 processor as with XSLT 2.0 doing `for-each-group group-adjacent` should help.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated above that I'm using version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic needs to go in the template for the parent of the link elements. Assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 it will be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::link">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </ul>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated above that I'm using version 1.0, would this methodology still apply?

Comment: Yes, you should have said. Now that XSLT 2.0 has been out for 5 years, it's becoming the norm. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is a lot more complicated: you'll need to use sibling recursion where the template for an element does apply-templates on its next following sibling.